# Is there such a thing as an "elisp bundle" for TextMate?

Tags: lisp, syntax-highlighting, elisp, bundle, textmatebundles

I started using [Code Collector Pro](http://www.mcubedsw.com/software/codecollectorpro) to organise and save my Emacs codes, and this software requires [TextMate bundles](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/) for syntax highlighting. They have a lisp bundle, but not an elisp bundle, at least not that I can see. I would think that the syntax highlighting would work under the lisp bundle, but for some reason it isn't happening.

I have never even seen any lisp code with syntax highlighting, so it is possible that the thing is working and I don't know, but I honestly don't think so, because the ;; before a line seems to me to be a comment thing, so anything after that should be in the color defined for comments which in my case is green. Here is a picture of my code collector screen with a piece of code written by [huaiyuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16240/huaiyuan) answering my question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935520/how-to-set-a-key-binding-to-make-emacs-as-transparent-opaque-as-i-want):

[image]

Is this looking as it should or is there something wrong?

Back to the initial question: is there a textmate bundle for elisp or a bundle like the ones from textmate I can download to get syntax highlighting?

Comment: Unhelpful comment: when you ask google this question, you get a link to this post. Damn, google works quick.

I see some syntax highlighting (if/let/strings) etc, but perhaps thats the default for only lisp. Have you looked for a textmate bundle editor?

Comment: A textmate bundle editor? No, I haven't... I didn't even know there was such a thing. If there isn't a simpler solution, such as a bundle that already exists, or I realise I am doing something wrong, then I might look for one  :) Thanks.

Comment: Why use collector pro?  Why not use a VCS like git or mercurial?  Just asking because a VCS would be useful to know in the long run, and Emacs has a nice integration with those.

Comment: I don't even know what a VCS is... Which one is better, git or mercurial? I would be interested to have a look, so any information you can give me would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought so, because anyone writing elisp is going to do it in Emacs so there wouldn't be any call for a Textmate bundle for it.

Comment: well, I don't believe I am the only person using Code Collector! In any case, maybe there is another bundle similar to those of TextMate that I would be able to include in Code Collector. They say you can include other bundles, I just don't know how, but if I have the bundle I am sure I can figure it out....

Comment: I've had a quick look at Code Collector, and superficially it looks like a really bad idea.  It seems to be focused on making copy-and-pasting code easier, which is a Bad Thing.  If anything, when you are coding you should disable copy and paste in your editor and force yourself to do things in a more reusable way.  The first time you find an error in one of those snippets and have to go and change it everywhere you pasted it, you are going to regret not creating a library or script.

Comment: Code Collector, for me, is a way to save pieces of code I found interesting but that I am not necessarily using yet. I guess once I am comfortable enough with Emacs I will be able to do that there, but for now I am lost. I have been pasting and copying pieces of code in drafts on my email, files I create on Emacs under various folders, etc, etc, so pasting and copying in Code Collector seems to help me organise the bits a bit better. How do you organise your code? I don't even know how to create a library or script  :(

Comment: I really enjoy learning/playing with code. I have had an interest in programming for a long time, and I even started a course some 8 years ago in Brazil, but they cancelled it halfway through because students dropped slowly until there was just me and one more. When I came to Australia I was only allowed to do one elective (one course not from my major), and I chose to do programming, even though I had no idea it would be useful one day. I thought it was only going to be for pleasure. The problem is, I am doing a PhD in Economics and I haven't done any thesis-related work for the last 4 weeks.

Comment: I am so hooked on Emacs, there is so much I want to do and learn, that I am finding it extremely hard to get back to my thesis. I have been promising myself I will start working on my thesis for days, but 5 minutes of typing on Emacs and I come across something I don't know or that I don't like and want to change. As soon as I start searching for an answer I find a zillion interesting things I can do and hours of reading, copying and pasting, bookmarking, .emacs experimenting, follow. When I realise the whole day is gone and all I did was deal with Emacs.

Comment: I had to ask my supervisor for a meeting this Friday to force myself to work on my thesis, but every day I am somehow drawn into the world of Emacs. From today I decided to abandon Emacs in favour of paper/pencil to do my work, but I am dragging myself and I can't stop thinking about Emacs. **I want to learn Elisp!**